# Navbar wont center

Tags: html, css

it's my first year on coding and i'm doing this for a school Project. We have to do a responsive site and i'm already facing a problem when trying to add a navbar to my site. Whenever i add it, it just goes too much to the left and wont go in the middle. I tried searching google for help but none of them worked so thought i'd register here to ask. Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background: white none; 
  color: black;
  /* jätetään ylämarginaalia navigointipalkin tilan verran */
  margin-top: 0em;
  /* jätetään vasempaan laitaan marginaalia saman verran kuin
     laitaan tuleva linkkialue vie */
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 24.5%;
  margin-top: 10
}
body {
    background-image: url("8.jpg");
}

#logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -180px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: Green;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #89F52B;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Etusivu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#games">Pelit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Palaute</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
  <li><a href="lomake.html">Lomake</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="logo">
<img src=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks center.

Comment: It is centered on me after I put it in a snippet

Comment: it's because you have used float:left - that means all the menu items will be pushed left.  If you make the li inline-block elements instead, you can just add text align center to the ul

Answer (score 0):

If you want your menu items centered inside the whole menu bar, just do as @Pete said:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: Green;
   text-align: center; <-----------
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white none; 
  color: black;
  /* jätetään ylämarginaalia navigointipalkin tilan verran */
  margin-top: 0em;
  /* jätetään vasempaan laitaan marginaalia saman verran kuin
     laitaan tuleva linkkialue vie */
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 24.5%;
  margin-top: 10
}
body {
    background-image: url("8.jpg");
}

#logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -180px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: Green;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #89F52B;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Etusivu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#games">Pelit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Palaute</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
  <li><a href="lomake.html">Lomake</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="logo">
<img src=""/>
</div>
```